# When trying to uninstall the adware WebPlat, I recieve an error saying, "The specified module could not be found." How do I solve this?

Tags: adware

Full error:
RunDLL
There was a problem starting C:\PROGRA~2\WebPlat\WebPlat.dll
The specified module could not be found.

I've had this adware for months and only today figured out what exactly it was called on my computer. When I try to uninstall it, I receive that error. I have no clue what to do and I cannot find an answer using Google.

Comment: You are getting this error because the file in question has already been removed from your system.

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking uninstalling adware doesn't work too well because of how the adware tries to make itself inherently difficult to remove in the first place.
I recommend a these steps to remove this adware and any others:

Download and install antimalwarebytes

Download and install Panda Cloud Cleaner (Not the antivirus, unless you want it)

Update both of them

Safe boot with neworking

Run antimalwarebytes and perform a full scan

Do whatever antimalwarebytes tells you to do after you run a full scan

Reboot (don't reboot again if antimalwarebytes already tells you to reboot)

Run Panda Cloud cleaner. When it shows the accept and scan screen, press the down arrow and 'Analyze all pc'

It may be wise to use the advanced tools to kill all processes while panda cloud cleaner is running. (which means that your computer will be unusable for the duration of the scan, because nothing but the cleaner will be running)

Then make the necessary changes based on what pandao cloud cleaner tell you to do. (READ CAREFULLY)

Reboot.

Clean pc